# Margin difference problems when left-aligning the rows in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, margins

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    {\huge
         \begin{bfseries}
         First row
         \end{bfseries}
    } \\
    \hline \\
    Third row
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### [image: Rendered document print-screen]

What I'd like to achieve is to left align all rows. As it stands, the first row is positioned more to the right compared to the third row. How can I left align the first and the third row?

Comment: And if you just tried `\begin{tabular}{l} \huge\ bfseries First row \\ \hline \\ Third row
\end{tabular}`?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you! Perhaps this should be closed as a typo then?

Comment: Probably you had an unwanted blank space after `\huge` , maybe added by the use of an environment in the place of `\bfseries`. The result of such a directive is limited to the cell in which it happens.

Comment: The extra space came from `\begin{bfseries}` which ended a line with `}` instead of `}%`.